# [pandas]: how to figure out what's inside a column

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to know which are the different variables in a dataframe, here an example to make you understand my issue

```
dic = { 'a': ['pippo', 'giacomo', 'giacomo', 'francesco', 'luigi', 'francesco', 'luigi'] }
df = pd.DataFrame(dic)
```

The dataframe is

```
 a
 pippo
 giacomo
 giacomo
 francesco
 luigi
 francesco
 luigi
 francesco
 luigi
```

What I am looking for is something that provides me as result

```
 pippo
 giacomo
 francesco
 luigi
```

So that I can understand which are the different things available in my dataframe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`drop_duplicates`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html):

```
df = df.drop_duplicates()
print (df)
           a
0      pippo
1    giacomo
3  francesco
4      luigi
```

If need specify column for checking duplicates:

```
df = df.drop_duplicates(subset=['a'])
print (df)
           a
0      pippo
1    giacomo
3  francesco
4      luigi
```

For different output - `numpy array` use [`unique`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.unique.html):

```
arr = df['a'].unique()
print (arr)
['pippo' 'giacomo' 'francesco' 'luigi']

L = df['a'].unique().tolist()
print (L)
['pippo', 'giacomo', 'francesco', 'luigi']
```